# Windows Server 2019 Essentials not showing System Protection > Create Restore Point

Tags: windows-server-2019, system-restore

The entire System Protection tab is gone!

I wanted to create a restore point before installing something, and I wanted to change some "Previous file versions" settings on a network share.

What's going on? I seem to get previous file versions at the regular interval, twice a day. But I can't see or create restore points, or see any settings. I haven't found others mentioning this issue. Could it be malware?

[image: No tab for "System Protection"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently that's not a thing in Windows Server 2019 Essentials. Which is weird, because the option to create a restore point shows in the start menu:

[image: Create a restore point]

I found a reply here that says this isn't an option for this OS:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90fd10a5-cb2c-4090-93a9-fd2ea478feca/windows-server-2019-standard-recovery-options

Answer (score 1):

The system restore point function is not available in Windows Server 2019 because there is a better tool: Windows Server Backup. It can be used for the same purpose but it can also do a lot more.

It is not installed by default, you must install it via Server Manager (it's in Features > Windows Server Backup).

To reproduce a similar behavior to a system restore point, open Windows Server Backup, then in the left pane click on Local Backup, then in the rightmost pane click on Backup Once, then follow the instructions [here](https://xpertstec.com/how-to-backup-restore-reset-windows-server-2019/) (essentially you select Custom Backup and then the input, and then where to store - select another drive), making sure to select "System State" as the input and nothing else (do NOT select the Windows partition, it will ask for which folders to backup then and it won't work because some folders include symbolic links!).

If you want to go wurther, you can even backup your EFI boot partition if you backup everything too ("Bare metal", this includes other partitions).

And if you want a more flexible tool, you can use 3rd-party system backup tools such as Macrium Reflect (but expect that they are expensive, but they do a better job than Windows’ restoration points because they copy the occupied sectors sector-by-sector so you can be assured that they will restore your partition as it was).